# C++ | Group elements of different types without polymorphism in arrays, vectors, sets, etc

Tags: c++, pointers, templates, memory-management, polymorphism

I have a class that stores components (a little bit like how an "Entity Component System" in a videogame would) as such:

```
class Components
{
public:
   
    template <typename T>
    T& AddComponent()
    {
        T* component = new T();
        m_Components.push_back(component);
        return *component;
    }

    //... More Templated code to use the stored components and delete allocated memory

private:
    std::vector<void*> m_Components;
}
```

I know this works to a point, because I tested it many times.

What I want to know is, if there are any other ways of accomplishing the same, **without using polymorphism**, that might be safer?

Also, if I want to delete the memory, is it OK to just call `delete` on a `void*` that could be pointing to many different types?

**Edit:**
If I have to use polymorphism I will but it would only be an empty class with no data.

The thing is not every instance of my `Components` class will not always have the same number of components. Imagine I have many different components with different behaviour like '`AudioComponent`', '`RenderComponent`', etc.

Sometimes an instance of this class will have only one or two components and other times it will have a lot more which is why it makes sense **to me** to save it in some type of dynamic array.

If there is any other way to accomplish something like this please point me to that direction.

Comment: Does https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any look like what you want?

Comment: Why would you want to avoid polymorphism? On the surface, it looks like just the right tool for the job.

Comment: Why _"without using polymorphism"_? If the types are unrelated, you could keep separate `vector`s for the unrelated types.

Comment: "*is it OK to just call delete on a `void*` that could be pointing to many different types?*" - no. The types' destructors will not be called in that case.

Comment: What you’re asking for is literally the definition of  what polymorphism is.

Comment: Side note: `std::shared_ptr` can be handy here. It knows how to destroy and free the object it holds even when you have no clue what it holds. Downside is `shared_ptr` is a bit expensive and doesn't necessarily describe the intended ownership of the object since now everybody with a copy of the `shared_ptr` is an equal owner.

Comment: @Passerby It actually looks like a solution thank you!

Comment: @user4581301 If I have to use polymorphism I would, but it would be just an empty class without methods or data

Comment: It sounds like you may be suggesting that these components have absolutely nothing in common, and if that's the case, yes, polymorphism makes little sense, but if they have nothing in common, why are they stored in the same pool? What do you gain from this? I think if you spend a little more time thinking over the abstraction you're attempting you'll find there are commonalities.

Comment: @user4581301 Added an edit that might explain better why I want to do this

Comment: You could abstract away the differences between the objects with a `DoSpecificStuff` method that draws the object if it's visible, plays a sound for an audio component, or fires itself out of a cannon for a [Gonzo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gonzo_(Muppet)) component. You can also have some fun with patterns like [visitor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern)

Comment: Add code that uses a component.  Heck, 2 different ones, even toy ones, that do toy actions.  Because your specs are best satisfied by making add component do nothing.

Comment: I'd like to see some part of "More Templated code to use the stored components". I wonder how `m_Components` is used, without any knowledge of what types those pointers point to.